# Max width on mobile view for a WordPress site

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I was supposed to correct the issue with responsivesness on mobile for this [site](http://materecclesiaecollege.com/). At this point I need help to figure out why this website behaves like this on a mobile view. I cannot figure out why there is horizontal scrolling the landing page. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to the social icons Css

Just paste that in your theme custom `style.css`

```
.norm_row {
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Wow this worked like magic, thanks alot. Please how did you got about it, have you encountered such an issue?

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps. Actually the thing is when ever you use `position` other then `relative` you need to give it `top` and `left` in order to make it work like width `100%` so that it will not go beyond your `view-port`. Kindly accept it as an answer by click check icon below up arrow icon so that it helps others....Cheers